# How do I restore Whatsapp from backup after skipping the restore option?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google-drive, chat-history

I accidentally skipped Whatsapp restore option when I changed my device and now my backup on google drive is overwritten. How can I get my old backup? It was about 2.3gb of my data and I need those chats. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have your old phone, recovery will be pretty easy

First of all make sure to turn on backup on your new phone.

**WhatsApp > Menu Button > Settings > Chat Settings > Backup conversations.**

[image]

Now, follow these steps:

1. Install the data recovery software for Android mobiles on your Windows PC using [this link](https://www.softwarert.com/android-recover-dcfon-win-download/).
2. Use the data recovery to scan your Android mobile phone. It supports up to 2000 Android mobiles, including Samsung mobiles, LG phones, HTC, Motorola, Lenovo, Nexus, ZTE, Huawei, Xiaomi, Blu, or other Android based phones and tablets.
3. Get back your lost WhatsApp messages on your old phone.
4. Now, you will need to transfer the/sd card/WhatsApp/folder from your old phone to the same folder on your new phone.

Hope this helps.